# Telepresence Connection Error - Traffic Manager version unsupported, must be 2.4.5 or higher while it is 2.6.5

Tags: telepresence

I have started to face this problem. While trying to connect, I am facing an error stating that my traffic-manager version is 2.1.5 and it should be at least 2.4.5.

"telepresence connect" command checks for new versions and modifies it if there is any new version exists. So I am thinking that started to create a problem. Because I was using it as normal.

When I check the connector.log file these two lines create the problem.

> connector/session : Existing Traffic Manager 2.6.5 not owned by cli or does not need upgrade, will not modify

> connector/session : failed to connect to root daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unsupported traffic-manager version 2.1.5. Minimum supported version is 2.4.5

So somehow I have two versions now while checking for the update it hits 2.6.5 but while trying to run it tries with 2.1.5. Trying to uninstall telepresence but it also faces the same problem and I couldn't locate and delete traffic-manager 2.1.5. My OS is Windows 11.

Because of that, I am kind of blocked with my tests. Any help will be well appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the question, a new version arrived, if anyone encountered this problem, please update telepresence to 2.6.6. It is fixed now.